# What is the difference between + + and direct+ 1 in C or C + +?

Tags: c

like `a++` and `a+1`, I know that `a++` = `a = a + 1` , besides this, what's the difference?

Comment: a++ is more compact and dangerous, and that's about it. C provides multiple ways to do the same thing, because why not.

Comment: Any half-decent C book or tutorial will explain all arithmetic operators and their differences. If you only want to increment by 1, do `++a`. If you want to increment by 1 but use the pre-increment value, use `a++`. If you want to add any other number, use `a += n`. And so on, and so forth. SO is not a substitute for basic language research.

Comment: `a++` and `a+1` are not the same, the later does not modify `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest difference is that `a+1` is just adding one to the variable `a`, but what do you do with it:

```
a = 3;
b = a + 1;
```

As a result, `a` still is 3 and `b` is 4.

But:

```
a = 3;
b = a++;
```

As a result, `b` is 4 but `a` is also 4 (`a++` means `a = a+1`, so `a` has been changed).